# Graphics Issue with Windows 11 - Can't display QR Codes & Graphics inconsistent

Tags: windows-11, whatsapp

I am having some graphics issues in Windows 11.

The image below is pretty typical of what a button looks like on any web page.

It is bearable - but I can't load What's app onto my PC because my smartphone doesn't recognise the QR code on the screen ( I assume because of the graphics issue )

I have

- LG Ultragear 32GN550 32 Inch Monitor
- No specific Graphics card - just onboard Intel UHD Graphics 750

I purchased everything specifically to support windows 11 so thought it would be fine

[image]

Comment: Have you installed the latest graphics drivers from Intel? Have you tried a different browser such as Edge, Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: Why are you leaping to assume the QR code on the display is the reason your phone can't recognize it?

Comment: @music2myear  because it worked with windows 10

Comment: @Mokubai - yes , same issue with all browers